# Representing Matroids Graphically

Tags: graph-theory, matroids

Is it possible to represent M a matroid on E = {a,b,c,d,e} with bases *ac,ad,ae, bc, bd, be, ce, de.* graphically? I'm familiar with the methods with larger bases but not bases of size 2. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this example yes.

We try to realize the matroid $M$ on ground set $E = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ as the graphic matroid $M(G)$ for some connected graph $G$ with edge set $E = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$. Note we can assume $G$ is connected because if $G$ is not connected we can chose a vertex from each connected component and "glue" together by identifying the chosen vertices without changing the graphic matroid.

Since your bases (which correspond to spanning trees) have size 2 we conclude $G$ must have 3 vertices. It is well know the number of edges in a spanning tree is one less than the number of vertices.

Now we need to construct our graph. If we let our vertex set be $V = \{1,2,3\}$ we notice that since our graph has only 3 vertices any 2 edges form a spanning tree of $G$ unless they connected the same two vertices. Since every edge connected 2 distinct vertices (your matroid has no loops since each edge is in some base) there are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ choices to assign each of our edges in $E$. So all edges look like $\{1,2\}$, $\{2,3\}$, or $\{1,3\}$. We just need to make sure it is possible to make a valid assignment given our set of bases. In your example it is.
Let $a = \{1,2\}$, $b = \{1,2\}$, $c = \{2,3\}$, $d = \{2,3\}$, and $e = \{1,3\}$.

Note here $e$ occurs with every other edge is a spanning forest, thus is must connect 2 vertices that no other edge connected. Also note $a$ never shows up in a spanning forest with $b$ (similarly for $c$ and $d$) which is why they can connect the same two vertices.

To summarize yes your example is a graphic matroid, and hopefully the above discussion helps you understand what can be done when you have bases of size 2.

Best,
John